# How to get all default keyboard shortcuts in Gnome 3?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

I want to query default shortcuts for Gnome 3 from my running system. Is that possible?

First, I want to make shortcut comparison between systems. Second, I want to see which shortcuts are modified. Settings app can somehow detect this.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible if you just fresh install and then dump the settings before altering anything.

Comment: @don_crissti if I only knew how to run official ISO in a container.. because containers could be stripped down versions. Then there is still the question how to dump all shortcuts?

Comment: On a fresh install if you run `gsettings list-recursively | grep -E 'keybindings|media-keys'` you should get _all_ DE shortcuts (but _not_ application-specific ones like gnome-terminal shortcuts...). If you want to see only the non-default ones use `dconf dump` which will only dump your settings.

Answer (score 0):

What version of gnome are you using ?

in gnome >=3.22 under the settings - device - keyboard
On top there's option to reset all.
Or try the super + esc, that's the restore keyboard shortcuts shortcut